# JQuery.ajax() method not executing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications

I have a have a button that calls a JavaScript method that looks like this:

```
processSelection = function(filename) {
  //alert('method reached');
   $.ajax({
      url: "sec/selectUsers.php",
      data: "filename="+filename,
      cache: false,
      dataType:'html',

      success: function(data) {
        //$('#uploader').html(data);
        $('#noUsers').sortOptions();
        values = $('#noUsers').children();

        for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          $(values[i]).bind('dblclick',switchUser); 
        }

        $('#addButton').bind('click',addSelection);
        $('#removeButton').bind('click',removeSelection);
        $('#submitButton').bind('click',addUsersToFile);
      },

      error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('script error, please reload and retry'); 
      }

   }); /* ajax */
}
```

It is not going to the `selectUsers.php` script, nor is it posting the error message.  When I click on my button 'add users' it does nothing.  The other methods: `switchUser`, `removeSelection`, `addSelection`, and `addUserstoFile` are already defined.

I am fairly new to JavaScript and php and have been assigned this project running maintenance on our website.  My php_error.log shows no error either. If anyone has any advice on this specific problem, or debugging in general I would very much appreciate it.

here is the click event:

```
 <input type="button" value="add users" onclick="processSelection('<?=$drFile['name']?>')"/>
```

Okay,

To simplify my problem, I have done this:

```
processSelection = function(){
              //alert('method reached');
               $.ajax({
                          url: "sec/testPage.php",
                          cache: false,
                          success: function() {
                                              alert('success');
                          },
                          dataType:'html',
                          error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                              alert('script error, please reload and retry'); }
                     });
```

}

where testPage.php is just a table with some values in it.

Now when I click the button it show 'success', but never shows testPage.php

Comment: do you check that the function is firing? Post your button `HTML`.

Comment: try having `url: "/sec/selectUsers.php",` instead of `url: "sec/selectUsers.php",`

Comment: is the URL you using actually correct?  is teh PHP file in a subdirectory 'sec' of the page where this javascript is being executed?

Comment: All browsers will let you view network request and responses by hitting F12.

Comment: How does the button look and what do you do with the data. If you uncomment the alerts do you get them. Look in chrome or Firefox with firebug and see in the console and the NET tab if you call the php at all

Comment: Can you post the click event code?

Comment: @thecodeparadox I know it is firing. that is what the commented alert was for.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes the URL is correct

Comment: I changed dataType to json and now it returns the error alert, but there is a page similar to this one that calls the exact same script and its datatype is html, so I don't think this is what I want.

Comment: @jcho360 when I add a forward slash a get the error alert

Comment: @mplungjan the data is the filename I wish to add users to. Here is a little backgroud:

Comment: With this application a user can upload a file and add other users to it at upload.  I am trying to add functionality to add users to existing files, using the same type structure.

Comment: @mplungjan and in the network console the selectUsers.php has a status of OK

Comment: Are you using POST or GET for the ajax? It's best practice to specify.   type: "POST"

Comment: @AlexReynolds thankyou for your response but neither worked out

Comment: I would suggest you to check the PHP error log as i think it's not a problem with the javascript.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses, including IE actually. I had to double check myself though.

Comment: You have the callback function on success : function(data) but no where do I see you doing anything with that data. Try success: function(data){ $('body').html(data) } and see if you get your table

Comment: @AlexReynolds yes that was the problem.  In my orginal file where I declared $(#uploader).html(data) the current file's id is actually 'uploaderr' while the page I copied this method from had an ID of 'uploader'.  I did not not catch this because A. I am new to web dev and B. I am not the original author.  But thank you for your solutino

Comment: just wondering, did you include the Jquery file and the `$(document).ready`, is it working?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType: 'HTML'
```

has to be before your success method as far as i know. If still does not work try the following:

it will not show the test page because you are not appending anything to your current body. Your script executes successfully if you see "success"on your screen. All you need to do is if you have html generated in your testPage, assign all html to a php variable and then just echo it instead of returning it like

```
 echo $myhtmlgenerated
```

and change

```
 success: function() { ....
```

TO

```
 success: function(result) { 
   $(body).append(result);
 }
```

or you can play around with it and specify a special div which will hold the content from that page.